# How to write arithmetics inline in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, word-usage, mathematics

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following sentence (this is about maritime and ports):

> If you are fixing a 10 days port call in a month having a 0.5 ratio would result in (10 x 0.5 = 5 days) of rain stoppages.

My question is: what is the best approach on writing inline equations in english? This should be technical, but pleasent to read

Comment: Why should it make any difference if the main text is in *English*? Just use whatever form you would in your own language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the text is meant for a english speaking technical audience; i'm trying to figure out what the expectations of a native speaker would be

Comment: Like I say, what makes you think native speakers of English would expect anything different from native speakers of your own language?

Comment: Your original form is better than the answer you accepted. Many readers of English technical documents have English as a second language. Simpler is almost always better.

Comment: @GlobalCharm The original form is not correct because it contains everything in a parenthetical.  At the least, the "5 days" portion should not be in the parenthetical.

Answer (score 1):

You said "this should be technical", so what you provided would suffice for most audiences.

If this is the only part of the text that is utilizing the equation is the one sentence, then doing it as a parenthetical as you did is fine.

You could restructure the sentence to remove the parenthetical:

> If you are fixing a 10 days port call in a month, having a 0.5 ratio would result in 5 days of rain stoppages because 10 days of port call multiplied by 0.5 is 5 days.

If your audience is assumed to know how the equation works already, you could omit the explicit math and streamline the sentence:

> If you are fixing a 10 days port call, you would have 5 days of rain stoppages with a 0.5 ratio.

It isn't applicable here, but if you ever use an equation that stands on its own (like Pythagorean Theorem), you'd want to add it as a separate figure and refer back to it when you use it.

(Note: You need a comma after the "if" clause since it is at the start of the sentence.)